# Selenium - How to get all frames with Pom Object pattern and PageFactory?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

The Webpage contains 2 frames.

My Selenium script :

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = ".//iframe") private List <WebElement> framesList;

public myPage (WebDriver driver){        
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public void goFrame2() {            
    if (framesList.size() >= 1) {
        driver.switchTo().frame(framesList.get(1));
    }
}
```

When I execute the script, the size of the liste framesList is always 1. Just one frame is detected. If  I add a Thread.sleep of 5 seconds before PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); the second frame is detected and the size of the list is 2.

Of course I don't want to use a Thread.sleep.
How to detect the 2 frames properly?

Julien

Comment: DId U know how to wait for elements in webdriver ???

Comment: Yes, I know how to wait for elements but I don't know how apply that in this case. At each load page the name of the second frame is different.

Answer (score 0):

So, you should explicitely find the xpath/css selector of the second frame (it will definitely differ from first one) and to wait untill it will appear. Only after that you can use your code. Here is an example how you can wait for frame containing class named "class":

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("frame.someclass")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AjaxElementLocatorFactory`

Create Constructor of class like below:

```
public class Login{

     public Login(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20), this);

    }
}
```

It will wait for elements for specified (20 secs) time.